# Basis Proof with addition

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V is a vector space, $\vec v, \vec w \in V$ and $\vec v \neq \vec 0$ and $\vec w \neq \vec 0$.

Prove that if {$\vec v_1, \vec v_2, ..., \vec v_k$} is linearly independent then {$\vec v_1 + \vec v_k, \vec v_2 + \vec v_k+...+\vec v_k + \vec v_k$} is a basis of <$\vec v_1, \vec v_2, ..., \vec v_k$>

So I would typically start by stating there are integers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_k \in \mathbb {R}$ where $(\vec v_1 + \vec v_k)x_1+ (\vec v_2 + \vec v_k)x_2+...+(\vec v_k + \vec v_k)x_k=\vec 0$. I know I want to isolate the {$\vec v_1, \vec v_2, ..., \vec v_k$} because we know it's linearly independent already and then convince that the others are just scalars that are equal to zero, however I'm not sure how to go about doing so. Once I prove linear independence I think I'll understand how to prove that it's a spanning set.

Thoughts:
Should I subtract $v_k$ from everything so I have: $\vec v_1x_1+ \vec v_2x_2,+ ...,+ +\vec v_kx_k=-v_k$? I don't believe that's even mathematically correct.

Comment: Where have $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ gone after the first sentence?

Comment: There were proofs completed before this one involving this information. I was just stating everything given to me. @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Expand the sum. Except for $v_k$, the coefficient is quite easy, and that of $v_k$ is not complicated either. However, it may happen that $k+1=0$ in the ground field, whihc would make the claim false.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Could you elaborate a little on "expand the sum" you make it seem like it's the obvious answer but I'm just not understanding or seeing what operation to take. Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the image set were linearly dependent. Then there are $a_i$ not all zero such that $\sum_{i\leq k}(a_iv_i+a_iv_k) = 0$. Since the first set is linearly independent, the first term cannot be zero, but since $v_k \neq 0$ and the $a_i$ are not all zero, neither is the second term. This implies $\sum_{i< k}a_iv_i = -(a_k+\sum_i a_i)v_k$, which in turns implies that $v_k$ is in the span of the other members, thus contradicts the assumption that the preimage is linearly independent. Hence the image must linearly independent. Furthermore, the two sets are of equal cardinality, so their span is equal if and only if they are linearly independent. It follows the image set is a basis for the span of the preimage.

Comment: Is $a_i$ just our scalars? If so then I understand I just am confused in the math as to how we got to $-(a_k+\sum_i a_i)v_k$

Comment: The $a_i$ are scalars. The second implication you mention follows because we assume 0=$\sum_{i\leq k}(a_iv_i+a_iv_k) = \sum_{i< k} a_iv_i + (a_k+a_i)v_k $.